# Material Design - AppCompat toolbar without showing shadow

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design, android-toolbar

I am using the toolbar from AppCompat V7 to replace the previous action bar and want to have the shadow of toolbar like the previous actionbar. but the toolbar doesn't have shadow by default, and I have tried the fixes mentioned from [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2k50fw/elevation_on_toolbar_not_working_on_prelollipop/). but without luck.

the code to set the shadow:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

The toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay">
```

the activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- activity view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include 
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:background="#EEE"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_header">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/user_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_icon"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/not_logged_in"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Setting in the style.xml:

```
<style name="myAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/drawer_shadow</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Can anyone help?

thanks!

update 1: with the suggestion from Willis, I get the shadow displayed, but it is not below the toolbar, instead it is to the left of the toolbar.
[image]

Update 2: I have noticed that if I don't set the windowContentOverlay in toolbar.xml and styles.xml, the shadow is actually on the top of the toolbar.
[image]

Comment: Those two are completely different shadows. The vertical one is that of `DrawerLayout`. It's supposed to be showing beside expanded drawer. The horizontal one is part of `windowContentOverlay` on APIs below `LOLLIPOP`. When you work with `Toolbar` widget the toolbar isn't part of window decor so the shadow starts at the top of the window over the toolbar instead of below it. You need to add an extra empty `View` below the `Toolbar` pre-`LOLLIPOP` with its background set to a vertical shadow drawable (8dp tall `#20000000` to `#00000000`). On `LOLLIPOP` you can set 8dp elevation on the toolbar.

Comment: Hi Eugen, you saved my day. This is exactly what I need, and it is working great under pre-Lollipop. this should be the correct anwser. Can you post it as the answer and I can accept this. thanks a lot!

Comment: Just did that, glad I could be of service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two are completely different shadows. The **vertical** one is that of `DrawerLayout`. It's supposed to be showing beside expanded drawer. The **horizontal** one is part of `windowContentOverlay` on APIs below `LOLLIPOP` (on `LOLLIPOP` it's `@null`).

When you work with `Toolbar` widget the toolbar isn't part of window decor anymore so the shadow starts at the top of the window *over* the toolbar instead of *below* it (so you want the `windowContentOverlay` to be `@null`). Additionally you need to add an extra empty `View` below the toolbar pre-`LOLLIPOP` with its background set to a vertical shadow drawable (8dp tall gradient from `#20000000` to `#00000000` works best). On `LOLLIPOP` you can set 8dp elevation on the toolbar instead.

Note: Use the same gradient but horizontal as the drawer shadow for best results.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the amount of shadow by using the `setElevation` method. For example:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(25);
```

Increasing/decreasing the value passed to `setElevation` will consequently increase/decrease the presence of the shadow effect.

Comment: thanks Willis, there is some confusion in my question, actually I need to show the shadow, but I didn't find the solution to make it work. is it possible to set other value for elevation to show the shadow?

Comment: Hi Willis, thanks a lot! I also set the theme for the app. I got the shadow displayed now, but it is not below the toolbar. any further suggestion?

Comment: Hmmm. See if specifying the elevation in the `Toolbar` attributes makes a difference. Add the following to the `Toolbar` layout: `android:elevation="20dp"`. And then remove `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(25);`

Comment: Thanks again Willis! there is some confusion from my side, I should mention that the emulator is with android version 4.0. what you suggested works for 5.0, and my issue is with 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

To show shadow under your toolbar please use AppBarLayout available in Google Android Design Support Library. Here is an example of how it should be used.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

To use Google Android Design Support Library enter following into your build.gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```